# "Could not load file or assembly" when configuring XSLT Mediator

Tags: 2011, xslt-mediator

I am trying to configure XSLT mediator. After adding a configuration entry, when I try to run, I get following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Docs\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.
>
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515). An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

DLL is located at right path and I am not sure why the prefix "file:///" is added to my path in exception trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to unblock the dll file. Right click on file, under General tab you can control/unblock this. Usually Windows Server locks the dlls in case they are sent over e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal location for this dll would be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin" So add this dll in this location.

In the tridioncontentmanagerconfig file add the below line in the mediators section

```
"<mediator matchMIMEType="text/xml" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.XsltMediator" assemblyPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.dll" />"
```

Thanks,

Sampath

Comment: I have tried that before but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

## How to Configure XSLT Mediator?

To enable the Mediator the Tridion CM configuration requires a small modification:

The file in the folder `[InstallationFolder]\Config` or `%TRIDION_HOME%\Config` is called `Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Preferably create a backup of this file and then open it in your preferred text editor and navigate to the `<tridion.templating>` element, then the `<mediators>` element and add the following line:

```
<mediator matchMIMEType="text/xml" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.XsltMediator" assemblyPath="D:\Tridion\bin\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.dll" />
```

If you changed the namespace or assembly name or path make sure that change is reflected in this configuration statement.

> **To start using the registered Mediator, restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application, IIS and the Publisher service.**

***@Yoav Niran** has given the above documentation very clearly on SDL Tridion World [XSLT Mediator 2011](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/xsltmediator2011.aspx). It's worth in reading.*

Comment: I have tried that, First I moved my dll to bin folder and updated the config file with new entry pointing to bin folder of tridion installation directory, I did a system restart but got the error above, then i tried to move that dll to "docs" folder on c drive, updated the config and did the system restart but got same error again, Is that a dll version of build problem?

Comment: Did you notice follwoing statement, I don't think this error is related to path "An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch"

Comment: @ShafaqatAli: Are you trying to load assembly from a network location?

Comment: No it is stored in my tridion installation bin folder, error description is so confusing.